# Network, usb ports, and display drivers are suddenly not working well

Tags: drivers, 16.04, display, network-drive

Please help me, I'm not really tech literate. Everything was working fine on my laptop until this morning. Started up and my display is on 800x300 resolution, I cant input anything when asked to unlock the sda, at this point I restart and it brings me to the grub menu which doesnt really do anything at all for me since I dont know how anything on this menu works besides going into recovery mode and resume boot sequence that puts me into user login menu.

All my files and programs are still here, still 800x300 resolution, I cant connect to the internet or use my usb mouse on any of the usb ports. I can use the keyboard however, but that's just about it. I cant do too much with it, I dont even know what to log. All I can say is the last changes/install I did yesterday which was installing apache, mysql, and php.

Please. Does anyone know what I can do here?

Edit:

```
sudo lshw -sanitize
computer
    description: Notebook
    product: X455LAB (ASUS-NotebookSKU)
    vendor: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
    version: 1.0
    serial: [REMOVED]
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-2.8 dmi-2.8 vsyscall32
    configuration: boot=normal chassis=notebook family=X sku=ASUS-NotebookSKU uuid=[REMOVED]
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       product: X455LAB
       vendor: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
       physical id: 0
       version: 1.0
       serial: [REMOVED]
       slot: MIDDLE
     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
          physical id: 0
          version: X455LAB.208
          date: 08/03/2015
          size: 64KiB
          capacity: 6400KiB
          capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb smartbattery biosbootspecification uefi
     *-cache:0
          description: L1 cache
          physical id: e
          slot: L1 Cache
          size: 32KiB
          capacity: 32KiB
          capabilities: synchronous internal write-back data
          configuration: level=1
     *-cache:1
          description: L1 cache
          physical id: f
          slot: L1 Cache
          size: 32KiB
          capacity: 32KiB
          capabilities: synchronous internal write-back instruction
          configuration: level=1
     *-cache:2
          description: L2 cache
          physical id: 10
          slot: L2 Cache
          size: 256KiB
          capacity: 256KiB
          capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
          configuration: level=2
     *-cache:3
          description: L3 cache
          physical id: 11
          slot: L3 Cache
          size: 3MiB
          capacity: 3MiB
          capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
          configuration: level=3
     *-cpu
          description: CPU
          product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-4005U CPU @ 1.70GHz
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          physical id: 12
          bus info: cpu@0
          version: Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-4005U CPU @ 1.70GHz
          serial: [REMOVED]
          slot: SOCKET 0
          size: 1599MHz
          capacity: 1700MHz
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 100MHz
          capabilities: x86-64 fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm epb tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid xsaveopt dtherm arat pln pts cpufreq
          configuration: cores=2 enabledcores=2 threads=4
     *-memory
          description: System Memory
          physical id: 14
          slot: System board or motherboard
          size: 2GiB
        *-bank:0
             description: DIMM [empty]
             physical id: 0
             slot: ChannelA-DIMM0
        *-bank:1
             description: SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MHz (0.6 ns)
             product: HMT325S6EFR8A-PB
             vendor: Hynix/Hyundai
             physical id: 1
             serial: [REMOVED]
             slot: ChannelB-DIMM0
             size: 2GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 1600MHz (0.6ns)
     *-pci
          description: Host bridge
          product: Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 0b
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
          configuration: driver=hsw_uncore
          resources: irq:0
        *-display
             description: VGA compatible controller
             product: Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
             version: 0b
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
             configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
             resources: irq:46 memory:f7800000-f7bfffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:f000(size=64)
        *-multimedia:0
             description: Audio device
             product: Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:03.0
             version: 0b
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
             resources: irq:49 memory:f7e1c000-f7e1ffff
        *-generic:0
             description: Signal processing controller
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 4
             bus info: pci@0000:00:04.0
             version: 0b
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: msi pm bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=proc_thermal latency=0
             resources: irq:16 memory:f7e10000-f7e17fff
        *-usb
             description: USB controller
             product: 8 Series USB xHCI HC
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 14
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.0
             version: 04
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi xhci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:43 memory:f7e00000-f7e0ffff
           *-usbhost:0
                product: xHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 4.4.0-51-generic xhci-hcd
                physical id: 0
                bus info: usb@2
                logical name: usb2
                version: 4.04
                capabilities: usb-3.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=4 speed=5000Mbit/s
           *-usbhost:1
                product: xHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 4.4.0-51-generic xhci-hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@1
                logical name: usb1
                version: 4.04
                capabilities: usb-2.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=8 speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usb:0
                   description: Mouse
                   product: USB OPTICAL MOUSE
                   physical id: 1
                   bus info: usb@1:1
                   version: 1.00
                   capabilities: usb-1.10
                   configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=100mA speed=2Mbit/s
              *-usb:1
                   description: Video
                   product: USB2.0 VGA UVC WebCam
                   vendor: Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd
                   physical id: 5
                   bus info: usb@1:5
                   version: 99.14
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=uvcvideo maxpower=200mA speed=480Mbit/s
        *-communication
             description: Communication controller
             product: 8 Series HECI #0
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 16
             bus info: pci@0000:00:16.0
             version: 04
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=mei_me latency=0
             resources: irq:47 memory:f7e24000-f7e2401f
        *-multimedia:1
             description: Audio device
             product: 8 Series HD Audio Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1b
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
             version: 04
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=32
             resources: irq:48 memory:f7e18000-f7e1bfff
        *-pci:0
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.0
             version: e4
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:40
        *-pci:1
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 3
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.2
             version: e4
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:41 ioport:e000(size=4096) memory:f7d00000-f7dfffff
           *-network
                description: Ethernet interface
                product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
                vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
                logical name: enp2s0
                version: 10
                serial: [REMOVED]
                size: 10Mbit/s
                capacity: 1Gbit/s
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
                configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168g-3_0.0.1 04/23/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
                resources: irq:45 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:f7d04000-f7d04fff memory:f7d00000-f7d03fff
        *-pci:2
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 4
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.3
             version: e4
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:42 memory:f7c00000-f7cfffff
           *-network
                description: Wireless interface
                product: AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter
                vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
                logical name: wlp3s0
                version: 01
                serial: [REMOVED]
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical wireless
                configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=4.4.0-51-generic firmware=N/A ip=[REMOVED] latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
                resources: irq:19 memory:f7c00000-f7c7ffff memory:f7c80000-f7c8ffff
        *-isa
             description: ISA bridge
             product: 8 Series LPC Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.0
             version: 04
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: isa bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=lpc_ich latency=0
             resources: irq:0
        *-storage
             description: SATA controller
             product: 8 Series SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode]
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
             version: 04
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: storage msi pm ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ahci latency=0
             resources: irq:44 ioport:f0b0(size=8) ioport:f0a0(size=4) ioport:f090(size=8) ioport:f080(size=4) ioport:f060(size=32) memory:f7e22000-f7e227ff
        *-serial UNCLAIMED
             description: SMBus
             product: 8 Series SMBus Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
             version: 04
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: memory:f7e21000-f7e210ff ioport:f040(size=32)
        *-generic:1 UNCLAIMED
             description: Signal processing controller
             product: 8 Series Thermal
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.6
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
             version: 04
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: memory:f7e20000-f7e20fff
     *-scsi:0
          physical id: 1
          logical name: scsi0
          capabilities: emulated
        *-disk
             description: ATA Disk
             product: HGST HTS545050A7
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/sda
             version: A3B0
             serial: [REMOVED]
             size: 465GiB (500GB)
             capabilities: gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt
             configuration: ansiversion=5 guid=89032691-3f8e-43c5-a9c3-e49e37538cfc logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=4096
           *-volume:0
                description: Windows FAT volume
                vendor: mkfs.fat
                physical id: 1
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,1
                logical name: /dev/sda1
                logical name: /boot/efi
                version: FAT32
                serial: [REMOVED]
                size: 510MiB
                capacity: 511MiB
                capabilities: boot fat initialized
                configuration: FATs=2 filesystem=fat mount.fstype=vfat mount.options=rw,relatime,fmask=0077,dmask=0077,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro name=EFI System Partition state=mounted
           *-volume:1
                description: EFI partition
                vendor: Linux
                physical id: 2
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,2
                logical name: /dev/sda2
                logical name: /boot
                version: 1.0
                serial: [REMOVED]
                size: 488MiB
                capabilities: extended_attributes large_files ext2 initialized
                configuration: filesystem=ext2 lastmountpoint=/boot modified=2016-12-13 20:27:54 mount.fstype=ext2 mount.options=rw,relatime,block_validity,barrier,user_xattr,acl,stripe=4 mounted=2016-12-13 20:27:54 state=mounted
           *-volume:2
                description: EFI partition
                physical id: 3
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,3
                logical name: /dev/sda3
                serial: [REMOVED]
                size: 464GiB
                capacity: 464GiB
                width: 512 bits
                capabilities: encrypted luks initialized
                configuration: bits=512 cipher=aes filesystem=luks hash=sha256 mode=xts-plain64 version=1
     *-scsi:1
          physical id: 2
          logical name: scsi1
          capabilities: emulated
        *-cdrom
             description: DVD-RAM writer
             product: DVDRAM GUE1N
             vendor: HL-DT-ST
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/cdrom
             logical name: /dev/cdrw
             logical name: /dev/dvd
             logical name: /dev/dvdrw
             logical name: /dev/sr0
             version: AS00
             capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram
             configuration: ansiversion=5 status=nodisc
```

Comment: May be a kernel update, on grub boot menu, select advanced then an older kernel version, see if it works.

Comment: Welp. That's embarassing.. Thank you! Is there anyway I can make this old one the default kernel again?

Comment: You may uninstall the last one and use DPKG pinning to skip that version.

Comment: Could you [edit] the question and add the output of `sudo lshw -sanitize`  and which version that broken kernel. It will be nice if you post an answer when you finish fixing your boot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was on the new kernel update(**`4.4.0-53-generic`**), the fix is to select the older version(for me it was this **`4.4.0-51-generic`** version) on the grub menu. Answered by [user.dz](https://askubuntu.com/users/26246/user-dz?tab=profile)

Comment: Nice, Would you set your own answer as accepted one, as this what worked for you. see [about] , there is  a gray/green check icon in a circle shape next to the answer (to the left). If this issue is not fixed in coming kernels, please consider submitting a bug report as explained here https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Bugs , feel free to ask for help in AskUbuntu.